# Saving data to data base while consuming through multiple consumers from a kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am new to kafka the problem i am facing is that I have 2 consumer that are consuming the data in batches from the kafka topic and want to save all the data fetched by each consumer to db. How to achieve that?
In the properties file listner.type=batch and max-poll-records=500 is set.
I have created a
Save message method that is  defined in the service class and i am calling the same method from both the consumer. While saving the records it is taking too much time.

Comment: Sorry the answer got deleted, don't know how@ Ajay Singh Pundir

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why are you writing a consumer instead of using Kafka Connect, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

If your consumer is "taking too long" and "doing too much", then rebalancing the consumer group and making no progress, then you simply need smaller batches rather than 500.

Otherwise, you need to improve the network connection between your app and the database, which is a hardware problem.